# Python socket OSError

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I have a file accepting an input as so

```
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
serversocket.bind(('localhost', 8088))
serversocket.listen(5) # become a server socket, maximum 5 connections

while True:
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    recvd_data = connection.recv(4096)
    if len(recvd_data) > 0:
        data = pickle.loads(recvd_data)
        print(data)
        serversocket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
```

The script prints the data output correctly, but then throws this error. I don't understand it nor have I been able to find a solution.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sending.py", line 21, in <module>
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 195, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: Well, you shut down the server socket, and then on the next iteration of the loop you try to accept from it again - what did you expect to happen?  Perhaps you meant to shut down the client socket instead.  Note that you code is fundamentally broken, since there's no reason to expect the entire payload to be received in a single `.recv()` call.

Comment: I meant the whole script to shut down. I've added a break line and moved the shutdown and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop for receiving data, but you close the `serversocket` after receiving the first batch. That's why the second call to accept fails